# Gulp: How to read folder name?

Tags: javascript, build, gulp, build-process, gulp-folders

I'm refactoring my Gulp build process so the user does not have to enter `V=1.2.88` etc.

Rather I would like the user to just type `major gulp build`, `minor gulp build` or `patch gulp build`. Which would then of course iterate the version number.

For this to work however I need gulp to read the folder name of the last build created:

[image]

My Current Gulp task which generates the version number:

```
var version = '';
var env = process.env.V; // V={version number} ie: V=1.0.1 gulp build

gulp.task('version', function() {
    return printOut(env);
});

function errorlog(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    this.emit('end');
}

function printOut(ver) {
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.blue.bold('Last build: '+paths.last));
    version = ver;
    if (version === undefined) {
        version = '0.0.0';
    }
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.blue.bold('##################################################'));
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.blue.bold('         Building Dashboard version '+version));
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.green.bold('~~           All change is detectable           ~~'));
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.blue.bold('##################################################'));
}
```

Anyone know how to accomplish this in Gulp?

This is what I found so far **[Gulp-folders](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-folders)**

So using the `Gulp-folders` plugin I created the following task which runs first:

```
    gulp.task('build:getLastBuild', folders(paths.lastBuild, function(folder) {
    console.log( 'Last version number is: '+folder);
    return lastVersion = folder;
    //This will loop over all folders inside pathToFolder main, secondary
    //Return stream so gulp-folders can concatenate all of them
    //so you still can use safely use gulp multitasking
    // return gutil.colors.blue.bold('Last build folder: '+folder);
    // return gulp.src(path.join(paths.lastBuild, folder))
    //     .pipe(console.log(' Getting last version number: '+folder))
    //     .pipe(lastVersion = folder);
}));
```

Now when I run my Build, check it out below! I'm getting the name of the folder in the console.log, however my process errors out :(

> TypeError: e.pipe is not a function

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the relation between "read the folder name" and your build task. However, I think you should use `yargs` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs), so you could do something like this `gulp --major 2.2.2 build`. If major is the latest version, maybe you just need to use node's `path` module, with a sort function to find the latest version

Comment: Well the idea is to ensure that the users does NOT need to know or type in any version number. I want to read the name of the folder, in my example above: `1.2.8` And then if it is `Major` 1+1, or `Minor` 2+1 etc...

Comment: What about https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver-utils to check the version and `fs.readdir()` or `fs.readdirSync()` to read the directories?

Comment: Ah yeah `fs.readdir` I'll check that out, also checkout the update I posted to my Question. I found a task that can check the folder name, but running into an error.

Comment: Regarding your empty action, checkout `gulp-if`: https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if , especially `gulpIgnore`

Comment: Still failing :( can you see what I added below my original question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'don't exactly get the part about the minor / majors, but regarding the list of directories, you could do the following:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    var dirs = fs.readdirSync('./build/assets');
    console.log(dirs);
    // do something with your directories
})

// and the async version:
gulp.task('async', function() {
    var dirs = [];
    var print = function(err, files) {
        // do something with your directories
        console.log(files)
    };

    fs.readdir('./build/assets', print);
})
```

Comment: Ok yeah this is exactly how I solved it :) Checking this, though since I have 2 folders in my `build/assets` I had to put a check in my code below to avoid iterating over the `static` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Got it! Though I admit it is a little rough, I googled node readdir and found [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname)
`console.log(__dirname);`

So with that, I created the variables and task below:

```
var fs   = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

gulp.task('build:getLastBuild', function() {
    return fs.readdirSync(paths.lastBuild).filter(function(file) {
        console.log(' build:getLastBuild: '+file);
        if (file != 'static') {
            lastVersion = file;
        }
        else {
            console.log('  lastVersion: '+lastVersion);
        }
    });
});
```

So now getting this! Now I have a string that I can manipulate to increase the version number when users run the build process.

[image]

Comment: Ahh, I was to slow to post my answer :S. Well done ;)